# Maven not finding properties for profile when OS Version tag used

Tags: maven

Trying to get a properties to be set based upon whether a user's OS is windows 10+ or below.

However whenever I enable the  command inside the OS tags, the properties are not set. Comment them out however and then the properties are set again.

Code below:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
                <version>(,10.0)</version>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <ChromeWebDriverLocation>${basedir}${file.separator}driver${file.separator}win32${file.separator}chrome${file.separator}chromedriver.exe</ChromeWebDriverLocation>
            <IEWebDriverLocation>${basedir}${file.separator}driver${file.separator}win32${file.separator}ie${file.separator}IEDriverServer.exe</IEWebDriverLocation>
            <SkipIETests>false</SkipIETests>
            <SkipEdgeTest>true</SkipEdgeTest>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>windows10Edge</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
                <version>[10.0,)</version>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <ChromeWebDriverLocation>${basedir}${file.separator}driver${file.separator}win32${file.separator}chrome${file.separator}chromedriver.exe</ChromeWebDriverLocation>
            <EdgeWebDriverLocation>${basedir}${file.separator}driver${file.separator}win64${file.separator}edge${file.separator}MicrosoftWebDriver.exe</EdgeWebDriverLocation>
            <SkipIETests>true</SkipIETests>
            <SkipEdgeTest>false</SkipEdgeTest>
        </properties>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

Comment: Are you sure than windows 10 introduce yourselve as 10.0?

Comment: Well the first line that gets spit out of the command line is like so:

`OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"`

Comment: changed it to dos... still no effect :/